# How to convert xlsx file to csv using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, csv, conversion

I have tried with `libreoffice`, `ssconvert`, `xlsx2csv` to convert the file but I am getting "command not found". Could you please help on that?

```
xlsx2csv
ssconvert file.xlsx file.csv
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv file.xlsx
```

These were i have tried it showing "command not found".

Comment: Have you installed these tools? What operating system are you using?

Comment: its not allowing me install. its there any other way ?

Comment: linux version 2.6.32

Comment: What is not allowing you? Again, what operating system are you using? If Linux, tell us what distribution. You cannot use tools you haven't installed so you need to install them first. We can't help with that if we don't know your operating system. Linux version 2.6.32 tells us your kernel, not your operating system. Are you using Ubuntu? Mint? Debian? Arch Linux? Something else? How did you try to install? How did it fail? Please ***EDIT*** your question and add these details.

Comment: 2.6.32 → CentOS 6 (Fedora12 based) : `cat /etc/redhat-release` ........... Example **xlsx2csv** ..... `xlsx2csv-1.06-5.fc12.noarch.rpm` provides `/usr/bin/convertxls2csv`, a perl script. .... Depends on `OLE::Storage_Lite, Crypt::RC4, Digest::Perl::MD5, Unicode::Map, Text::CSV_XS`

Comment: Link examples : fc12 https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/12/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/xls2csv-1.06-5.fc12.noarch.rpm .... fc25 https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/25/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/x/xls2csv-1.07-7.fc25.noarch.rpm ..... Unpack rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The toolkit called `csvkit` from https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ contains utilities for converting various formats into CSV. There are also tools in the kit for querying, reformatting, and just generally working with CSV files in various ways.

For example,

```bsh
in2csv file.xlsx >file.csv
```

See also [`in2csv --help`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html).

`csvkit` may be installed as a non-root user using `pip install --user csvkit`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this great and easy cli tool:
https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/usage/#xlsx2csv

```
csvtk xlsx2csv input.xlsx -n "sheetName" >output.csv
```